# Access and manage local storage from Splinter?

Tags: python, local-storage, browser-automation, splinter

I would like to retrieve, manage and store data in local storage.

Is there an API for that in splinter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no storage API available with splinter, but you can build your own with evaluate_script and execute_script :

```
import json
from splinter import Browser

class LocalStorage:

  def __init__(self, browser):
    self.browser = browser

  def set(self, key, value):
    self.browser.execute_script(\
      "window.localStorage.setItem('{}',{})".format(key, json.dumps(value)))

  def get(self, key):
    return self.browser.evaluate_script(\
      "window.localStorage.getItem('{}')".format(key));

  def get_all(self):
    return self.browser.evaluate_script("""(function(){
      var items = {}, ls = window.localStorage;
      for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; i++)
        items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k);
      return items;
      })()""")

  def remove(self, key):
    self.browser.execute_script(\
      "window.localStorage.removeItem('{}');".format(key));

  def clear(self):
    self.browser.execute_script(\
      "window.localStorage.clear();")
```

Usage example:

```
from splinter import Browser

browser = Browser()
browser.visit("http://mdn.github.io/web-storage-demo")

# get the local storage
storage = LocalStorage(browser)

# get an item
print storage.get("bgcolor")

# set an item
storage.set("size", 452)

# remove an item
storage.remove("size")

# get all items
for key, value in storage.get_all().iteritems():
  print key + ': ' + value

# delete all items
storage.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if your driver on splinter is able to execute a java script, you can do something like this (I have used it in selenium):

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
url='http://xxx.xxx.xxx/'
driver.get(url)
scriptArray="""return Array.apply(0, new Array(localStorage.length)).map(function (o, i) { return localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)); }
                )"""    
result = driver.execute_script(scriptArray)
print(result)
```

The original post from where I learn this technique last years is [here](http://scraping.pro/extract-browsers-local-storage-with-python/).